# jQuery form validation default message replace not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation plugin and want to replace the default message. Below is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#creatProfileForm").validate({
        rules : {
            firstName : {
                required : true
            },
            lastName : {
                required : true
            },
            password : {
                required : true
            },
            cityOfLiving : {
                required : true
            },
            messages : {
                firstName : {
                    required : 'First Name is required',
                },
                lastName : {
                    required: "Last Name is required",
                },
                password : {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When I try to submit the form, I am getting the default message of "This field is required".

Can anyone kindly tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please put the messages json after rules like the example given below(taken from jquery plugin doc, http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)

```
$(".selector").validate({
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: "Please specify your name",
        email: {
            required: "We need your email address to contact you",
            email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
        }
    }
});
```